# Change AppData path for specific Program

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-registry, storage

I need to change the path of AppData of specific programs.

Example of these programs:

- MATLAB 2014a
- Adobe Photoshop CC 2014
- Adobe Illustrator CC 2014

---

*Operating System:* **Microsoft Windows 8.1**

Comment: _Why_ do you need to do this? I'm pretty sure you didn't just decide "I need to change the AppData path;" you probably have some other problem you want to solve, and there's a fair chance changing the AppData path isn't the right approach.

Comment: link them to a second drive: https://bitsum.com/junctionmaster.php, http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

Comment: @cpast To free up storage from the Windows partition

Comment: @magicandre1981 Do this solution requires these third party programs to be running while running my programs? I need to preserve computer resources (Processor/RAM).

Comment: no, you use them only once.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Which one of them you recommend me to use?

Comment: Try both. I use LSE most the time

Comment: @magicandre1981 From a quick preview of both, I think LSE have more features. Thanks! :)

Comment: @magicandre1981 I would set the original folder to a removable media storage, and the virtual folder would be on Windows partition (C:). Do you think there would be any risk?

Comment: play a bit and look if it works.